# C# multithreading GameOverlay.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, graphics

I have 2 classes each one of them running on separated thread, when I run my program I can see that text drawing on my screen but it's blinking, I have suspect that BeginScene and clearscene is the issue but I don't know how to do it without it, can you help me please... thanks

mainform

```
                new Thread(frm1Thread).Start();
                new Thread(frm2Thread).Start();

        private void frm1Thread()
        {
            frm1.Initialize();
            while (true)
            {
                frm1.Update();
            }
        }
        private void frm2Thread()
        {
            frm2.Initialize();
            while (true)
            {
                frm2.Update();
            }
        }
```

frm1

```
            _graphics = new Graphics
            {
                MeasureFPS = true,
                Height = _window.Height,
                PerPrimitiveAntiAliasing = true,
                TextAntiAliasing = true,
                UseMultiThreadedFactories = true,
                VSync = true,
                Width = _window.Width,
                WindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero
            };
            var gfx = _graphics;
            gfx.BeginScene();
            gfx.ClearScene(_transparent);
            gfx.DrawTextWithBackground(_font, _red, _black, 10, 10, "frm1");
```

frm2

```
            _graphics = new Graphics
            {
                MeasureFPS = true,
                Height = _window.Height,
                PerPrimitiveAntiAliasing = true,
                TextAntiAliasing = true,
                UseMultiThreadedFactories = true,
                VSync = true,
                Width = _window.Width,
                WindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero
            };
            var gfx = _graphics;
            gfx.BeginScene();
            gfx.ClearScene(_transparent);

           gfx.DrawTextWithBackground(_font, _red, _black, 10, 10, "frm2");
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: winforms, sorry

Comment: You also forgot to mention what `Graphics` is and what its methods are doing. Plus how come that `frm1.Update();` & Co. don't throw an exception. Btw, `Update()` is a sync method (assuming frm1 and frm2 represent Form instances).